# Restful and return types

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, architecture

(Names different from real things for simplicity)

We have a SQL Server database with a Person table. We also have an Address table, which contains street addresses and an Id. The person table has a PhysicalAddressId and a WorkAddressId column, along with the normal Person data.

There is an existing Api, called 'People', which brings back a list of Person objects.

There is an existing Person/{Id} api call, which brings back a specific person. I have been asked to add the addresses and some complex other stuff to that Person call. The procedure is complex to get that data, taking around 50ms, compared to the `SELECT ... FROM Person Where ID =...`

The object (for both api calls) that goes back, is the same. (Initial issue?). So, when you call for a Person, you get Address fields populated. But when calling for People, you only get the Person related fields populated. i.e. It's sorted from the '`SELECT .. FROM Person`' query, while the single 'By Id' comes from a complex stored procedure.

The issue is that when you consume the api, by calling for a specific Person, you get a fulling populated model. But the List version has nulls for 'Physical Address' nodes.

Is the right thing to do, to have a different type for the List vs the single Person (List of 'Person' models and Single 'ComplexPerson' model)? Or there better ways to handle this issue.

Comment: What are the ``people`` api calls like? ``Post`` method, similar to a query, passing any arguments in the body?

Comment: @matt, these are both GET methods in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can follow the rest principles and do something like this:

Endpoint: 
Person/{id}

Will return:

```
Person{
    id:
    name:
    etc
    Address{
        id:
        name:
        etc
   }
}
```

Then for a list you do this

Endpoint: 
People

Will return:

```
People
[
Person{
    id:
    name:
    etc    
    Address{
        "href": "https://yourapi/address/{id}"
    }    
},  
Person{
    id:
    name:
    etc    
    Address{
        "href": "https://yourapi/address/{id}"
    }    
}]
```

So basically there are normally two things you can do when you call a resource that is linked to another resource.

1) Populate it with the actual resource
2) Add a link to where you can access the other resource.

To expand on this you can add querystring parameters to alter the behavior and let user decide if they will see a link or the populated resource.

It is normally preferable to return the link only when you are returning a list to reduce the amount of resources that the server has to access.

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution. I’ll put it past out architects. Just not sure how the person object in .Net, prior to serialisation, can have either a list of urls, or a single Address object. Will need to see if thats possible.

Comment: @Craig, two things, first: as you said, is your architecture fine with this approach?, second: sometimes it is not desired to make entities (addresses here) directly accessible, e.g. for security reasons. Apart from that, excellent answer for considering the principle of HATEOAS.